# React-router / history prevents 'beforeinstallprompt' event from firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, react-router-dom, history.js

I have a Progressive Web App that uses react-router with the history package for navigation. On a certain route, i want to display a button that allows the user to directly install the product to their device. The display of the button listens to the `beforeinstallprompt` event. It stores the event in state and fires the event when the user presses the button, fairly straightforward code, as seen here:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import Button from 'components/common/button';

function InstallRoute() {
  const [deferredPrompt, setDeferredPrompt] = React.useState(null);

  const beforeInstallPrompt = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setDeferredPrompt(event);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', beforeInstallPrompt, true);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', beforeInstallPrompt, true);
    };
  });

  function install() {
    if (!deferredPrompt) return;
    deferredPrompt.prompt();

    deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        // accepted
      } else {
        // dismissed
      }
      setDeferredPrompt(null);
    });
  }

  return (
    <InstallWrapper visible={deferredPrompt !== null}>
      <Button onClick={install}>Install app</Button>
    </InstallWrapper>
  );
}

const InstallWrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 32px;
  display: ${props => props.visible ? 'block' : 'none'};
`;

export default InstallRoute;
```

The problem however, is that the `beforeinstallprompt` event **only** fires on initial load. Which means it only fires when you either refresh, or when navigating to that route using `window.location = '/installroute'`. When navigating to the install route using `history.push` or `NavLink` from the react-router package, the event will not fire.

The install button works as intended when refreshing or a hard location change, but naturally, i want it to work with react-router/history as well. I don't want to pollute the project with dirty location changes.

Is there any solution to this? Is there maybe a different type of route element i should use for  the install route, or an alternative to `history.push`?

Comment: I am also looking for the same answer. If you found anything insightful, please share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

try this
event = new Event('beforeinstallprompt')
window.dispatchEvent(event)

[PWA: How to retrigger beforeinstallprompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403429/pwa-how-to-retrigger-beforeinstallprompt)