# how to test beforeinstallprompt event on desktop to check it's working

Tags: progressive-web-apps, beforeinstallprompt

I have integrated PWA features in react web app and beforeinstallprompt event gets triggered in production app when opened in mobile. I want to trigger this event on desktop development environment.
Is there a way to achieve that.
I referred [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403429/pwa-how-to-retrigger-beforeinstallprompt#answer-50626433) regarding this problem and updated chrome browser settings but the event is not triggered.

Comment: it also not triggereds if you have the app installed on your computer. do you also have deleted your storage?

Comment: Have you fully removed any previous tests installed but going to this URL in Chrome? --> chrome://apps/

Comment: no, I have not deleted storage? which storage are u referring to?

Comment: I have not installed this app before. checked in chrome apps.

Comment: press F12, go to "Application" then go to "Clear Storage" and clear it

Comment: `window.addEventListener("appinstalled", function(){})` gets triggered if your app is installed

Comment: remember it has poor browser support

Comment: You are tying from an HTTPS URL?

Comment: I am trying from http:localhost:3000

Comment: it should work from localhost without SSL

Comment: HTTPS is a requirement for PWA installation. If you can, try a free host like Glitch to test if you do not have an HTTPS host.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the browser. beforeinstallprompt is triggered on chrome 102 and edge 102 for me but not on firefox 101. it is not triggered if the app is already installed.

Check here for a list of supported browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent