# Force SPA Add to home screen popup to display even after adding to home

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a PWA using react JS

There is a requirement that we need to display the add to Home screen even after the App has been added to the Home screen for the first time

Can any body suggest if this is possible and how?

INFO: Mostly this app will be run on Google Chrome and Safari

Comment: Did this answer solve your issue? If not, please add more info on why you need to show the install banner even after installing to see what alternate option we have.

Comment: Hello Anand, you are right, the use case can not be possible in live environment, only can be used in some Dev environment or targeted systems,

We needed this because one of our client had this wierd requirement, you know clients can expect too much sometime

But we did inform the client that this is not possible as it is not allowed in chrome and safari, thanks for your time @Anand

Comment: I am accepting this as the correct answer as this is not possible normally, may be we can try out something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Refer to this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50356149/1057093) You simply can't do that, unless you want to do it in specific development/test machines where you can set the below chrome flag,

```
chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks
```

You can't expect all your end users to set this flag, so this can't be a solution for all the real users.

I also don't see why you would have to show the banner even after adding to home screen, for any other use case. Browsers don't allow this for obvious reasons. It will be annoying the user, if the prompting is left to developers. Linked answer have more clarification on the same.

Comment: You are correct, I figured out this is not possible usually so may be we can try out something else some other day