# Is "Add to home screen" feature of PWA supported in iOS?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, angular-service-worker, a2hs

I am building an app using PWA. I am using Angular. Basically, it is a media application that plays videos. It is working fine on Android and the "Add to Home screen" popup also comes in Android devices, but in iOS devices "Add to Home screen" does not appear.

Does iOS support the "Add to Home screen" feature?

Answer (score 6):

Please refer to the following articles listed below for the iOS PWA functionality

> With iOS 11.3, Apple has silently added support for the basic set of
>   new technologies behind the idea of “Progressive Web Apps” (PWAs).
>   It’s time to see how they work, what are their abilities and
>   challenges, and what do you need to know if you already have a
>   published PWA.

https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-on-ios-are-here-d00430dee3a7

PWA on iOS isn't automatically available like on Android, there are some additional settings you will have to change to allow for the popup to show on Safari iOS.

Additionally from the following stackoverflow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160348/pwa-how-to-programmatically-trigger-add-to-homescreen-on-ios-safari), there is a link to making it available for iOS [without the user having to change their settings.](https://www.netguru.co/codestories/few-tips-that-will-make-your-pwa-on-ios-feel-like-native)

Comment: which type of additional setting require? Please elaborate.

Comment: from the medium article linked above
```the user has to go to your PWA URL somehow within Safari and then manually press the Share icon and then “Add to Home Screen.” There will be no indication that a website you are visiting is a PWA.```

Answer (score 0):

**This code helps me to show the install popup on iPhone.**

```
if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
   console.log('display-mode is app installed');
}
else{
  console.log('display-mode is browser');
}
```

we can show a custom popup to install.

*Thank you*