# PWA Add to Homescreen

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

i have create a add to homescreen with serviceworker.js and manifest, but this start's by pageload, i want to do it with a button.

```
<button onclick="downloadapp();">Download Web-App</button>
        
<script>
    function downloadapp(){
            
     if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        console.log("Will the service worker register?");
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(function(reg){
            console.log("Yes, it did.");
         }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("No it didn't. This happened:", err)
        });
     }
     
        }
</scirpt>
```

This is not working.

Comment: What exactly does "This is not working" mean? Can you give us more details like error messages? Also, take a look at this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen#javascript_for_handling_the_install , maybe this will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all for handling the Install option you need the service worker to be installed already. I suppose you want to add a customized button to install your web application for that you can add some event listeners as following

Your code needed to be updated with

```
<script>
     if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        console.log("Will the service worker register?");
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(function(reg){
            console.log("Yes, it did.");
         }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("No it didn't. This happened:", err)
        });
     }
</script>
```

Code to handle service worker status and install event

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", (e) => {
        // Prevent the mini-infobar from appearing on mobile
        e.preventDefault();

        // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
        window.deferredPrompt = e;
        console.log("Registerd event");
        // Update UI notify the user they can install the PWA
        window.localStorage.setItem("pwainstalled", "false");
        //this.showInstallPromotion();
    });
    window.addEventListener("appinstalled", (evt) => {
        // Log install to analytics
        console.log("INSTALL: Success");
        window.localStorage.setItem("pwainstalled", "true");
    });
</script>
```

Functions to manage and display button of install

```
<script>
    function installButtonDisplay() {
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn.setAttribute("id", "install-button");
        btn.innerHTML = "Download Web-App";
        btn.onclick = function() {
          installPWA();
        }
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }
    function installPWA() {
        if (window.deferredPrompt) {
            console.log("inside window.deferredPromp if condition");
            window.deferredPrompt.prompt();
            window.deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
               if (choiceResult.outcome === "accepted") { 
                  removeButton();                   
                  console.log("User accepted the install prompt");
               } else {
                  isInstalledState(false);
                  console.log("User dismissed the install prompt");
               }
           });
        }
    }
    function removeButton() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('install-button');
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
</script>
```

Note: You might need to add or remove code as per your use case, this is just for reference and better understanding.

Comment: thanks it works but unfortunately it doesn't work with iphone, do you have a solution?

Comment: Hello @Mertkan, for iPhone you can refer following StackOverflow answer, Please accept, upvote, and share answer if it helped you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160348/pwa-how-to-programmatically-trigger-add-to-homescreen-on-ios-safari