# How do I make my website turn into an app using "Add to homescreen" function on iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

On iOS, if you open certain websites (like trygalaxy.com) and press "Add to homescreen", it kinda turns into an app, but this doesn't apply to all websites, so how do I add this feature to my own website?

When I do this on my own website it just opens safari, I want it to act like an app

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160348/pwa-how-to-programmatically-trigger-add-to-homescreen-on-ios-safari?rq=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PWA is good idea. Use this file in root folder to create fullscreen PWA.
manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "APP 2.3",
  "short_name": "APP 2.3",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "http://localhost/app.html"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like you are trying to add PWA to your website. you can you iconic or capacitor js

https://ionicframework.com/
https://capacitorjs.com/

maybe this will help or share a screenshot URL/Gist(https://gist.github.com/).