# Add To Home Screen / add Bookmark on screen for Every Single page

Tags: javascript, browser, progressive-web-apps

When the user opens the website to the mobile device, the browser should ask `Add To Home Screen` or `Add Bookmark To Screen` like PWA for every single page I mean different for every URL.

> Note: Here I'm not talking about `PWA` (Progressive Web App), I know how to create PWA and I've created it.

I just want to know that what I am asking is possible or not to ask the user to add a bookmark on every single page he opens just like PWA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cant. [Here is my detailed answer on why.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50356149/1057093)

That would be so annoying to a user and no browser will let you do that (even if you think its a valid use case for your scenario). 
Thats why browsers don't give control over how the install prompt event is triggered. Install prompt can be caught and shown once in the right time when you think user will be convinced to install it. If the user defers to install, you need to wait for a long time to catch the same event again to show the prompt again. How long is something depends on the browser and there is no standard time defined by any browser vendor.

Basically, if browser thinks user might like to add again based on the length and frequency of usage, then it will trigger the prompt event again. But that wont be in the same session/day for sure.