# How to prompt "save in the home screen" in a Flutter Web App (both mobile and desktop)

Tags: flutter, dart, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

Opening [Flutter Gallery](https://github.com/flutter/gallery) [web app](https://gallery.flutter.dev/#/)

the user get prompted to add the app to the home screen as shown below

for both desktop

[image]

and mobile

[image]

what steps should I follow to achieve this without messing with JS ([js answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50356149/9836706))

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

While the popup in the image that you have mentioned , that is automatic .It  automatically fires up when you meet several criteria (and which are always true for flutter web apps , mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/native#criteria)) .

code :

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
  });
}
```

which is present in index.html handles the pwa functionality

Comment: in my case doesn't happen :/
 https://iapicca.github.io/#/

Comment: can you show me the example website which you made , the gh-pages link gives 404

Comment: sorry, my bad, I'll re-deploy it in a moment, I might have found the cause :)

Comment: redeployed (has other problems... but still doesn't offer the "save feature"

Comment: Ok! i inspected both of your sites , both manifest.json and and flutter_service_worker.js file are not being served , can you check that they are actually present in your web build or are not being ignored?

Comment: @AmanVerma are you still around for helping please? My app is also not showing save to home screen and I am not sure what is going wrong - https://c4demo.web.app.