# Pwa installation own button installation in JS + HTML + CSS

Tags: javascript, html, button, installation, progressive-web-apps

I know how to do a pwa integration and the browser proposes the installation with the message "Add --- to the home screen". My wish is as follows: I would like to set up on the integrated PWA website a personalized button l "Install mobile version" in **HTML** so that my users can install the progressive web app as needed, especially when they wish. They will not necessarily wait for the browser to offer them the installation. I have already done the PWA integration and the browser already offers the installation. Problem is, I don't really know how to go about my permanent web app progressive **install button in html + javascript**  that users will see on my website outside of what the browser offers.

Here is my service-worker.js and my index.html

```js
var CACHE_NAME = 'PWA-installation';
var urlsToCache = [
  'index.html',
  './',
  'styles.css',
  'scripts/network.js',
  'scripts/ui.js',
  'scripts/clipboard.js',
  'scripts/theme.js',
  'sounds/blop.mp3',
  'images/favicon-96x96.png'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!-- Web App Config -->
    <title>pwa</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>

<body translate="no">
    <header >
      
        <a href="#" id="install" class="icon-button" title="Install PWA" >
             Install PWA
        </a>
    </header>
 
    
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="column">
       
    </footer>
    
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="scripts/network.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/theme.js" async></script>
    <script src="scripts/clipboard.js" async></script>
   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make an in-app button that triggers the PWA "Add to Home Screen" install banner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332119/is-it-possible-to-make-an-in-app-button-that-triggers-the-pwa-add-to-home-scree)

Comment: This not solve my problem

Comment: Show us that at least you have tried, show us your code, I had the same problem and I'm 100% sure that answer solved it, you can also read this: https://web.dev/customize-install/

Comment: @GuillermoRomero   I have difficulty creating a button in html that will control the installation of the progressive web app

Comment: @GuillermoRomero  Here is my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, you only need to implement this part:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64727286/8716572

First you need to use this code to listen to the beforeinstallprompt event:

```
let deferredPrompt;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function (e) {

  // Prevent the mini-infobar from appearing on mobile
  e.preventDefault();

  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  deferredPrompt = e;
});
```

Then you need to add the event listener to your button:

```
var buttonInstall = document.getElementById('install');

buttonInstall.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  // Show the install prompt
  deferredPrompt.prompt();
});
```