# PWA for IOS on safari and chrome with javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

I managed to create a custom pwa install button in html javascript that works well on an android only based on this documentation:
[Android Pwa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553152/pwa-installation-own-button-%20install-in-js-html-css/70601996?answertab=createdasc#tab-top)

My current problem is getting it to work on safari ios and chrome for ios.

I have read from my research that browsers like safari  do not support pwa installs.

I would now like to ask if there is at this time an alternative to create a custom "Install ios app" button in my PWA. Thank you for your propositions.

Comment: Please look at this: https://blog.wick.technology/pwa-install-prompt/ Very well explained

Comment: Thank you for your documentation, but this explanation is based on the react But I want to achieve it in html and javascript

Answer (score 2):

As of April 2023, There is no way to automatically install a PWA on iOS, but it can be done manually through the Safari browser menu.  That being the case, you'll need to detect whether or not the user is on iOS and if they are, display a different button, one that pops up instructions, similar to those in this screenshot.

[image]

Unfortunately, these instructions are only valid for Safari on iOS.  If your users are using Chrome (or any other browser on iOS) there's no way to install the PWA. So ideally you also detect the browser, and if they're not using Safari, popup a different set of instructions, ie. that this can only be done in Safari, or hide the button altogether.